# How to remove that tree structure at the top on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I try to remove that part at the top. If someone has a link to another question that resolve that, I'll be pleased.

[image: Exmaple of the tree]

I promise, I've searched online and even on Stackoverflow but I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable `stickyScroll`. To disable it:

1. Open `Settings` panel from `File > Preferences > Settings` or the `Manage` icon at left bottom
2. Open the `settings.json` file from the right top corner file icon (Displays this overlay on hover: **Open Settings JSON**) in the `Settings` panel
3. Use this command: `"editor.stickyScroll.enabled": false` to disable it. If you would like to enable it again, then you can change `false` to `true` or remove this command from the JSON file since its default value is already `true`

Hope, it's clear and helpful