# Auto closes some lines horizontally in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I didn't know how to describe the problem, so I apologize for the title. As you can see in the picture, the editor closes some codes automatically. I don't know how this happens and how can I turn it off? [image]

Comment: I guess, your issue is related to the `Sticky Scroll` feature. This question can be the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78046972/how-to-remove-that-tree-structure-at-the-top-on-visual-studio

Comment: Çözdü hocam elinize sağlık.
It works, thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! (Sizinde hocam elinize sağlık)